# iOS not executing asynchronous or complete code of Javascript (Cordova app) after pause event

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, dom-events

I want to executive asynchronous function when pause event get fired.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
   console.log("puase fire"); //it get print in console
   setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("after 1 second"); //it not get print in console. 
   }, 1000); 
}, false);
```

Timeout function get executive when resume but if killed or close app then complete code execution is pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's documented on the [iOS Quirks](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/cordova/events/events.html#ios-quirks)

> In the pause handler, any calls to the Cordova API or to native plugins that go through Objective-C do not work, along with any interactive calls, such as alerts or console.log(). They are only processed when the app resumes, on the next run loop.

So, if you want to call some native method it won't work, and console.log neither.

Comment: okay thanks for your value information. is there any other way?

Comment: You can make your app work in background, but Apple only allows that if it's a music app, or uses VOIP, or some other strict reasons. Or if you want to execute native code, you can create a plugin that listen for the enter background and then execute the code inside a `application beginBackgroundTaskWithName`, that allows some extra time before the app finally sleep (see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)